# Socket.io creating multiple connections

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm integrating socket.io into my project. I'm using the code below and it's creating 6 connections after the first request. Is this normal?

```
server.listen(
    port,
    function()
    {
        console.log('Node.js server listening on port ' + port);
    }
);

server.on(
    'connection',
    function(socket)
    {
        console.log('socket.io connection');
    }
);
```

And here is the console.log output:

```
Node.js server listening on port 3000
socket.io connection
socket.io connection
socket.io connection
socket.io connection
socket.io connection
socket.io connection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this result because (as far as I understand) your `server` object is an instance of node's [`http.Server`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) class, and is not connected with Socket.IO at all. In your example, `'connection'` event is being fired on *any* request the your node server. It looks like browser sends 6 requests to your node server: page, favicon.ico, and 4 other requests (it might be images, javascripts, css, etc.).

To integrate socket.io into your project you may use the following code:

```
var http = require('http');
var sio = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    //you request handler here
});

var io = sio(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('socket connected');
    //now you can emit and listen messages
});

var port = 3000;
server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Node.js server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

And, of course, the [official documentation](http://socket.io/docs/) might be very helpful. Good luck :)